# React document.getElementById() is null when it is findable in the browser console

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Today When I switched from ejs to react I faced the error that document.getElementById is null, and when I went to the browser console, I could easily find it!

Here is my script:

```
document.getElementById("registerForm").addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();

...
  
})
```

Here Is The Error:
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

and here is the snapshot of the browser console showing the element:

[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n9d1.jpg)

[The document in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjC7X.jpg)

Please Help!

PS: I am a beginner to reactjs.

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with react, however you're absolutely not supposed to add event listeners like that. With react, you use `<form onSubmit={e => this.handleForm(e)} ...>` in your Component. https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#making-an-interactive-component

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but imagining there is a  hacker, he can change the data and do anything! right?

Comment: ?? What's your point? He can do that either way. You can never rely on client-submitted information, you always need to validate server-side anyway.

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH............................., Sorry forgot about that. :P. THANKS!